# using tuple() on a list does not return an identical tuple according to typing

Tags: python, tuples, typing, typechecking

I created a class with a list attribute containing an int and a float.
I then tried creating a getter method to return the list as a tuple.

```
from typing import Tuple, List

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lst = [3, 5.0]

    def get_lst_as_tup(self) -> Tuple[int, float]:
        return tuple(self.__lst)
```

while it seems to work properly, PyCharm presents a problem:

`Expected type 'Tuple[int, float]', got 'Tuple[Union[int, float], ...]' instead`

after seeking stack overflow I tried several other implementations for the return statement. that resulted in the same error:

<s>`return (element for element in self.__lst)`</s>

`return tuple(element for element in self.__lst)`

`return (*self.__lst,)` this specific implementation resulted in :

`Expected type 'Tuple[int, float]', got 'Tuple[Any]' instead`

I was able to get rid of the error by using `return self.__lst[0], self.__lst[1]`

but I do not understand why it does not accept the other implementations.

Notes:
I did not use the word tuple elsewhere in the file.
This error occures even when this is all there is in the file.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Do you pass additional flags for execution?

Comment: No, none.
But as a clarification, it is not an error. The method can be used, it is the IDE that marks the return statement as different then expected.

Comment: My take is, that instantiating a tuple by a list will make it hard to type-check its content as it is a-priori not clear how many elements the list will contain. As a consequence pycharm assumes an arbitrary number of int and floats and infers the type Tuple[Union[int,float]]. Type hints work correctly if you pass a tuple instead.

Comment: Please don't tag [tag:pycharm] unless this is actually a bug involving or caused by the actual IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example

```
return (element for element in self.__lst)
```

I doubt that you got the same error as this in fact returns a generator and *not* a tuple.

Your other attempts

```
return tuple(self.__lst)
return (*self.__lst,)
return tuple(element for element in self.__lst)
```

are all valid approaches to convert the list `self.__lst` into a tuple. Of course, the most readable is `tuple(self.__lst)`, so you should probably stick with this.

I think the suggested type `Tuple[Union[int, float], ...]` is still too narrow here. You are converting a list which is of variable length into a tuple. There is no way of knowing which length `self.__lst` will have in your program. Consider this:

```
m = MyClass()
m._MyClass__lst.append("hello")
r = m.get_lst_as_tup()
print(r)
```

Output:
`(3, 5.0, 'hello')`

Which is of type `Tuple[int, float, str]`.

However, when you use `return self.__lst[0], self.__lst[1]` it is guaranteed that the function will return a tuple of length 2 (or throw an exception if the list became smaller than length 2).

Comment: Thank you! that's a great answer.    P.S. You're right about the generator, sorry :)